# show div and hide another div using checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i need to hide `div1` and show `div2` when `checkbox1` is checked

i have used below code but it didn't work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function valueChanged() {
        if ($('.checkbox1').is(":checked"))
            $(".div2").show();
        else
            $(".div1").hide();
    }
</script>
```

Html

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" onchange="valueChanged()"  />
<div class="row" id="div1">Show Div 1</div>
<div class="row" id="div2" style="display: none">Show Div 2</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead you can just use `toggle()`

```js
function valueChanged() {
  $('.row').toggle();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" onchange="valueChanged()" />
<div class="row show" id="div1">Show Div 1</div>
<div class="row" id="div2" style="display: none">Show Div 2</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep it JS based your logic isn't quite right. Corrections below:

HTML Update:

```
<input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" onchange="valueChanged()">
<div class="row" id="div1">Show Div 1</div>
<div class="row" id="div2" style="display: none;">Show Div 2</div></div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function valueChanged() {
        if ($("#checkbox1").is(":checked")) {
            $("#div2").show();
            $("#div1").hide();
        } else {
            $("#div1").show();
            $("#div2").hide();
        }
    }
</script>
```

If you want to do it with just CSS instead add a class or id to the checkbox as well and use the `~` selector. You'll also want to remove the inline display none on the div2.

```
#div2 { display:none; }
#checkbox:checked ~ #div1 { display:none; }
#checkbox:checked ~ #div2 { display:block; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You code is not correct. It should be like this:

```js
function valueChanged() {
  if ($('#checkbox1').is(":checked")) {
    $("#div1").hide();
    $("#div2").show();
  } else {
    $("#div1").show();
    $("#div2").hide();
  }
}

// OR you could just use toggle()
function valueChanged2() {
  $('.row').toggle();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" onchange="valueChanged()"  />
<div class="row" id="div1">Show Div 1</div>
<div class="row" id="div2" style="display: none">Show Div 2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You use not correct access to elements

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function valueChanged() {
        if ($(this).is(":checked"))
            $("#div2").show();
        else
            $("#div1").hide();
    }
</script>
```